# how to enable pager like behavior in a shell buffer?

Tags: buffers, shell

I can't believe I'm saying this, but one thing that is "nice" about windows cmd is the pager. When I do `man grep` in a bash shell inside emacs buffer it spits out the entire content at once. Is there a way/mode to have emacs buffer to halt outputting text and ask if I want to see more.

Running `GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2018-05-30` on "ON NOOO! But can't run anything else" --> Windows 10.

here is what I have for running a bash shell buffer.

```
  ;;git bash
  (defun git-bash () (interactive)
    (let ((explicit-shell-file-name "d:/Installed_progs/Git/bin/bash.exe"))
      (call-interactively 'shell)
      (setq explicit-bash.exe-args '("--noediting" "--login" "-i"))))
```

To make it more concrete, here is what I see if I run `man grep`
[image]

The command output filled the entire screen and keeps going until the end of the text.

Here is what I see when I run the same command in win cmd

[image]

Pages shows only what fits in one screen and waits. Is there any way to have that type of behavior in a bash shell in emacs?

Comment: You have asked a question about eshell (as per your title), and rejected an answer because you don't use eshell. Further, there are several ways to run a shell in Emacs, and neither of the ones I use (M-x shell and M-x term) will dump an entire man page to the terminal when you do `man grep`. Can you please explain how you are running a shell in Emacs, and also what version of Emacs and which OS you have? Otherwise this question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @tyler you are right, the title was wrong. Typed too fast. I've updated the title and included some additional info

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. I think this must be Windows-specific, as the behaviour I see using your code on Linux is a little different. I do have Emacs on a Windows machine that I can take a look at. In the meantime, you might like `M-x man grep <return>. It's only one more keystroke (you need to type `M-x` at the beginning), but it gives you something much nicer than a simple pager. At least, I think `M-x man` works on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using EShell the following works:
`man grep`: Add `"man"` to the list value of `eshell-visual-commands` and use `*man grep` instead of `man grep` at the command line of Eshell.

Background:

- The commands in `eshell-visual-commands` are started in `term-mode` which allows paging if the command does do that.
- `man` has an Eshell-own Elisp implementation `eshell/man` which calls the usual `man` command of Emacs. If an Elisp version of a command exists you can enforce calling the external command by prefixing it with a star. Therefore, you need to call `*man` instead of `man` in Eshell.

---

`git log`: Follow the instructions in the documentation of the variable `eshell-visual-subcommands`:

> An alist of the form
>
> ((COMMAND1 SUBCOMMAND1 SUBCOMMAND2...)
>     (COMMAND2 SUBCOMMAND1 ...))
>
> of commands with subcommands that present their output in a
>   visual fashion.  A likely entry is
>
> ("git" "log" "diff" "show")
>
> because git shows logs and diffs using a pager by default.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I don't really use Eshell. I'm using git-bash shell as my main.

Comment: @A_P Since you did not specify the shell in your question this remains a valid answer. You should be more specific in your question. If you edit your question please mark it as EDIT to keep this a valid answer of your original question.